# Is ChromeCast only for Video?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Can ChromeCast and/or the Google Cast protocol run apps that are not video?

In other words, is it possible to create an html5 app that runs on the ChromeCast and controlled by the smartphone/tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the receiver is an arbitrary HTML5 application. Of course, you should make sure it's suitable to be displayed on a TV with no attached keyboard and mouse, etc.

See the [Google Cast receiver documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver) for some more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed `but also allows for app-specific free-form messages to be transmitted` in the receiver documentation.

Comment: Google has a sample tic-tac-toe application here https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-tictactoe.